# Accidentaly rsync --delete, /usr is affected, any way to check and reinstall missing component?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, restore, ubuntu-server

I was working on a ubuntu 12.04 server, testing to restore a backup (how ironic, I didn t done the "real" backup).

Tried a `rsync` with `--delete` flag on `/`, I `ctrl+c` almost immediately, but rsync prompted a lot of files to be deleted (enought for putty to can t handle it all).

Is there any way to restore the system in a stable state?

**I DO NOT ASK ABOUT RESTORING DATA**, thoses are gone and I don t care about them, only about getting back to a ***stable system***. I can t access physically the server to make a clean reinstall easily, any other way (or definitive no) is worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch :-(

If there's enough of a system left for it to run, you could try

```
apt-get --reinstall install `dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}'`
```

It's pretty drastic stuff, but it sounds like you're in a pretty drastic state.  Good luck.

Comment: Well, it do is still running, so I can try.

Comment: Just wondering what it does exactly? It reinstall dpkg which tell awk to do... I don t know.

Comment: It tries to force a reinstall on all installed packages... but it depends on certain things still being there, so it might not work for you if your `rsync` got too far.

Comment: `/var/lib/dpkg/statu` is missing, preventing dpkg from starting. (Also, ask me for superuser when I m root)

Comment: Ugh I'm sorry to hear that.  If it was me I'd bite the bullet and reinstall.  Any time spent negotiating the physical access problems will be dwarfed by a manual repair and sorting out the myriad problems you'll face further down the line.

Comment: That s what I ve doing, thanks for the help thought.