# rsync don t work as expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, rsync

I have a script which download and compress a folder of a remote server (example: /home).

I m trying to make the "restore" script, but I have a strange behavior.

restore.sh:

($1 is IP adress, $2 is full path)

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "Error"
    exit 1
else
    D=$(mktemp -d)
    echo "From $D/$2"
    echo "To user@$1:/$2"
    tar xfz /backup/$1.tar.gz -C $D
    rsync -ncavzPe ssh --partial --delete $D/$2 user@$1:/$2
    rm -r $D
    exit 0
fi
```

Let s say the remote server is 127.0.0.12, and I want to restore /home.

```
$ssh 127.0.0.12
$password:
$ls /home/user
a b c x y z
$logout
$sh restore.sh 127.0.0.12 /home
From /tmp/tmp.R8iAewFEIR//home
To user@127.0.0.12://home
user@127.0.0.12's password:
sending incremental file list
home/
home/user/
home/user/1
home/user/2
home/user/.cache/
home/user/.cache/motd.legal-displayed

sent 351 bytes  received 40 bytes  46.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
$
```

Isn t it supposed to delete a, b, c, x, y and z? Is it just because of the dry-run? Is it sending to another folder? [I broke a server trying similar things](https://superuser.com/questions/725076/accidentaly-rsync-delete-usr-is-affected-any-way-to-check-and-reinstall-mis) yesterday and am too afraid to try it without the -n.

Comment: Instead of `rm -r $D` you should use `trap "rm -r -- "$D" EXIT` right after creating the directory

Comment: For your own safety you should use `set -o errexit -o nounset` at the top of the file. This will also make the `exit 0` at the end redundant.

Comment: [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: In any sane program, dry-run means that the command will not change or remove anything which was already on the system before the command was run. So I'd say this is very much expected behaviour. See `man rsync` for details.

Comment: @l0b0: I know the effect of dry run, what I was afraid of was trying without it to see where the file would be effectively put. What does `trap` do? Also, where are quote missing?

Comment: [Wiki article on signal traps](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "Error"
    exit 1
else
    D=$(mktemp -d)
    echo "From $D/$2"
    echo "To user@$1:/$2"
    tar xfz /backup/$1.tar.gz -C $D
    rsync -cavzPe ssh --partial --delete $D/$2/* user@$1:/$2/
    rm -r $D
    exit 0
fi
```

I was forgetting to enter in the folder in the source of rsync.